# Google Chrome - How to save usernames only

Tags: web-browser, google, chrome

I don't want Google Chrome saving my passwords, I only want it to save my username.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is a custom GreaseMonkey script.

The majority of password fields are typically of input type *password*. GreaseMonkey could look for any such fields and when they are updated by Chrome instead of the user, XOR in a Base64 symmetric key before Chrome dispatches the form.

This way the GreaseMonkey script could ask for the symmetric key when you start Chrome and it is stored in memory until Chrome closes; Chrome has no persistent copy of the real passwords; and yet you only need to remember one password. The symmetric key can be stored in any truly secure password store the rest of the time.

Although all this does assume that Chrome's built-in password store is actually weak. I don't recall any article saying it is.

Comment: Chrome stores passwords in plain text without any encryption. I would classify that as "weak".

Comment: Yeah. That would be weak. Homeopathic security even.